# Kubernetes Security Policy fsgroup not working

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

Trying to mount Kubernetes volume to a pod(running as non-root) with fsGroup SecurityContext option. But the volume is still mounted as root and getting permission denied from the pod when trying to do write operations on the filesystem

Created the Persistent volume:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-demo
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  nfs:
    server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    path: /nfs/data/demo
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Persistent volume claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: demo-vol
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeName: pv-demo
```

StatefulSet for the application deployment. The container image starts as user 1001(belonging to group 0)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: demo-app
  labels:
    app: demo-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: demo-app
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-app
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 0
        fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
      containers:
      - name: demo-app-container
        image: <theImage>
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /store
              name: demo-vol
      volumes:
        - name: demo-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: demo-vol
```

Comment: I've had issues with file ownership on NFS before. it's possible the /store path is owned by root because it was created by the kube controller responsible for mounting it. A possible workaround is using mkdir within the pod. o running an initcontainer as root and chown it to the correct ID. Either might solve this. The issue has been around for some time now. https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/issues/260

Comment: Have you tried setting ```chmod 0777 /nfs/data/demo``` on nfs server ?

Comment: if you use `chmod 777` you might as well not bother with any of this...

Comment: Did the workaround proposed by @Ernst help you with your issue?

Comment: changing the permission to 777 would work obviously. But that is not something I want to do on my production environment.

Comment: I found a post where they created an image for a build when they [Use fsGroup from the Pod's securityContext to determine uid/gid for mount opts](https://github.com/juliohm1978/kubernetes-cifs-volumedriver/pull/9/files). I think it can be useful for you.